# Use asyncio tasks in a separate thread

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, python-asyncio

I have a requirement for a project to use several hundred threads and each thread should run an asynchronous function. At the end, I need to collect results from all the threads. I have following example but it works synchronously.

```
import asyncio
import concurrent.futures

async def count():
    print("One")
    # here I need to use an asynchronous function
    await asyncio.sleep(2)
    print("Two")
    return "some result"

async def main():
    futures = []
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
        for _ in range(5):
            future = executor.submit(count)
            futures.append(future)

        results = [await f.result() for f in concurrent.futures.as_completed(futures)]
        print(results)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Code above outputs:

```
One
Two
One
Two
One
Two
One
Two
One
Two
['some result', 'some result', 'some result', 'some result', 'some result']
```

Expected output:

```
One
One
One
One
One
Two
Two
Two
Two
Two
['some result', 'some result', 'some result', 'some result', 'some result']
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code does not use eventloop correctly, note that `asyncio.run` runs the passed coroutine, taking care of managing the asyncio event loop, finalizing asynchronous generators, and closing the threadpool. see more details in https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.run

do it below will properly reuse the same eventloop.

```
import asyncio
import concurrent.futures

async def count():
    print("One")
    # here I need to use an asynchronous function
    await asyncio.sleep(2)
    print("Two")
    return "some result"

async def main():
    loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
    
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=5) as executor:
        # this in fact return coroutine object
        coros = [await loop.run_in_executor(executor, count) for _ in range(5)]
        results = [await f for f in asyncio.as_completed(coros)]
        print(results)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

**output**

```
One
One
One
One
One
Two
Two
Two
Two
Two
['some result', 'some result', 'some result', 'some result', 'some result']
```

Answer (score 0):

Use could use event loop's [`run_in_executor()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.run_in_executor) to schedule the tasks and [`asyncio.as_completed()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.as_completed) to loop over the results:

```
async def main():
    futures = []
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
        for _ in range(5):
            futures.append(await loop.run_in_executor(executor, count))

        results = [await f for f in asyncio.as_completed(futures)]
        print(results)
```